# What is this component? (Labelled 338 M828)

Tags: identification, components

There is a 3 pin/connector component connected to the PCB below. It is labeled with "338" and "M828" (the image quality is too low to show this). What purpose does it serve?
[image: Picture of component]

[image: Picture of component]

Comment: What is that thing, some kind of domestic cooker?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It's a digital photo frame from 2005, but if you leave it running long enough you probably can use it as a cooker. There's no documentation anywhere on the internet apart from [this user manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1071818/Technika-Sr08.html).

Comment: IR  receiver for the remote?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany That's most likely it, after putting it back in the case I noticed it was positioned by a small transparent part of the front panel. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There are Transistors named BC388, which would fit with the case and number of pins...

Comment: It looks like IR receiver, just like @SpehroPefhany said. Maybe TSOP38338? https://www.vishay.com/docs/81743/tsop381.pdf